# Problem with std::getline() and std::cin.get()

Tags: c++, istream

can you help me
Why this code can't be swap

```
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str1);

    cout << "Enter another string: ";
    cin.get(str, 100, '\n');
```

Into

```
    cout << "Enter  string: ";
    cin.get(str, 100, '\n');
```

```
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str1);
```

when i ran
First code
Output :

```
Enter a string: hai
Enter another string: hello
```

Second code
Output :

```
Enter another string: hello
Enter a string:
```

I can't input anymore, it just directly returned 0

Is it because of delimiters?

Answer (score 2):

[`std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) leaves the newline character in the stream so if you use `std::getline` afterwards, it'll directly read that newline character.

You can get rid of it like so:

```cpp
std::cin.get(str, 100, '\n');
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::getline(std::cin, str1);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nfjrP1WYh)

But, it's easier if you don't mix `std::getline` and `std::istream::get`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) for `std::istream::get`:

> The delimiting character is not extracted from the input sequence if
> found, and remains there as the next character to be extracted from
> the stream (see getline for an alternative that does discard the
> delimiting character).

I.e. the **difference** is that `std::getline` disacrds the newline delimiter character. If you use `std::istream::get` it stays in the stream buffer, and when you try to extract the 2nd string you will get it into your variable.

Regarding your specific example, it's a better to use either `std::getline` or `std::istream::get` consistently, rather than mixing them up.
If you have a good reason to mix them, see how to in **@TedLyngmo**'s answer.